# Google Sheet Script Null Error during loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, xml-parsing, google-sheets

I am parsing an XML file using the following loop and Google Scripts, but one of the Childs is missing in the XML File at one location. So the entire process returns a null value.  How do i retrieve all of the data that is not null?

```
> function stugas() {
>   var live = new Array();   
>   var url ="http://xml.pinnaclesports.com/pinnacleFeed.aspx?sportType=Football&contest=no&sportSubType=NFL";
>   var parameters = {method : "get", payload : ""};   var xml =
>   UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, parameters).getContentText();   
>   var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
>   var games = document.getRootElement().getChild('events').getChildren('event');  
> if(document == null) {
>     document.getRootElement().getChild('events').getChildren('event');   }   for (var i=0; i < games.length; i++) {
>       vegas=[games[i].getChildText('event_datetimeGMT'),games[i].getChild('participants').getChildren('participant')[0].getChildText('participant_name'),
>                 games[i].getChild('participants').getChildren('participant')[0].getChildText('visiting_home_draw'),
>                 games[i].getChild('participants').getChildren('participant')[1].getChildText('participant_name'),
>                 games[i].getChild('participants').getChildren('participant')[1].getChildText('visiting_home_draw'),
>                 /**games[i].getChild('periods').getChildren('period')[0].getChild('moneyline').getChildText('moneyline_visiting'),
>                 games[i].getChild('periods').getChildren('period')[0].getChild('moneyline').getChildText('moneyline_home'),**/
>                 games[i].getChild('periods').getChildren('period')[0].getChild('spread').getChildText('spread_visiting'),
>                 games[i].getChild('periods').getChildren('period')[0].getChild('spread').getChildText('spread_home'),
>                 games[i].getChild('periods').getChildren('period')[0].getChild('spread').getChildText('spread_adjust_visiting'),
>                 games[i].getChild('periods').getChildren('period')[0].getChild('spread').getChildText('spread_adjust_home'),
>                 games[i].getChild('periods').getChildren('period')[0].getChild('total').getChildText('total_points'),
>                 games[i].getChild('periods').getChildren('period')[0].getChild('total').getChildText('over_adjust'),
>                 games[i].getChild('periods').getChildren('period')[0].getChild('total').getChildText('under_adjust')]
>       
>       
>       live.push(vegas);
>     }
>     return live;   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write your inner loop this way you could then test for each element to see if they exist or not (did that for the moneyline only here):

```
vegas = [];
var game = games[i];
vegas.push(game.getChildText('event_datetimeGMT'));
var participant = game.getChild('participants').getChildren('participant');
vegas.push(participant[0].getChildText('participant_name'));
vegas.push(participant[0].getChildText('visiting_home_draw'));
vegas.push(participant[1].getChildText('participant_name'));
vegas.push(participant[1].getChildText('visiting_home_draw'));
var period = game.getChild('periods').getChildren('period')[0];
if (period.getChild('moneyline')) {
  vegas.push(period.getChild('moneyline').getChildText('moneyline_visiting'));
  vegas.push(period.getChild('moneyline').getChildText('oneyline_home'));
}
else {
  vegas.push("");
  vegas.push("");
}
var spread = game.getChild('periods').getChildren('period')[0].getChild('spread');
vegas.push(spread.getChildText('spread_visiting'));
vegas.push(spread.getChildText('spread_home'));
vegas.push(spread.getChildText('spread_adjust_visiting'));
vegas.push(spread.getChildText('spread_adjust_home'));
vegas.push(period.getChild('total').getChildText('total_points'));
vegas.push(period.getChild('total').getChildText('over_adjust'));
vegas.push(period.getChild('total').getChildText('under_adjust'));
```

Comment: Thank you Harold, you fixed it